# Not able to Set CopyLocal to True

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a weird issue. I'm not able to set CopyLocal property of a referenced dll to True for my VS 2015 project. When I change the property to True, it is automatically set to False. Embed Interop Types is set to False.
Also the version is shown as "0.0.0.0".

Can any one advice me the cause of this issue?

[image]

Comment: Not sure, if it has something to do with your issue. But do you have VS 2015 opened in admin mode?

Comment: Yes, it is opened in admin mode

Comment: What is the name of the DLL?

Comment: It has just no idea whatsoever what you are trying to do.  Resolved = False, there is no Path.  Hard to guess how you added the reference, it should not be left out of the question.

Comment: yes, I agree, it would be worth for you to delete and add the reference to DLL once again. Ideally, it should have something in the Path field, and many other fields which are currently blank in your case.